# How does iOS detect the completionHandler is not used

Tags: ios, swift

There is a function on AppDelegate which is called when the app is started for background fetch. `application(_:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:)`

If the `completionHandler` of this method is not used, the system can detect it **instantaneously**, and warns about it. It is not a timeout warning.

> Warning: Application delegate received call to
>   -application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.

However, even if the completion handler is used on an unreachable code, the system does not warn.

How does the system know it? Can I write my own library which warns when the handler is not used?
I suspect it is related to @escaping and reference counting, but I could not find anything.

```
//Warns that the handler is not used
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        while(true) {

        }
    }
}

//Does not warn that completion handler is not used even though the code is never executed.
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        while(true) {

        }
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }
}
```